# Named exports with HOCs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

## The problem

Lets consider I have a SFC (I am using TypeScript) and export it like:

```
export const AppShell: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
  ...
)
```

All fine. But now before I export my component I want to wrap it with a HOC like `withStyles` from [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/). Now I want to do something like:

```
const AppShell: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
 ...
)
```

And export it as:

```
export const AppShell = withStyles(styles)<Props>(AppShell);
```

Of course this will result in an error:

```
[ts] Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'AppShell'.
```

## Solutions with trade-off

As far as I know I will now have two options:

1) Use an default export:

```
export default withStyles(styles)<Props>(AppShell);
```

Because I am not a fan of default exports because of their many [disadvantages](https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad) I am not ok with that solution.

2) Use a prefix like 'Raw' for my components before they get wrapped:

```
const RawAppShell: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
 ...
)
```

Export it like:

```
export const AppShell = withStyles(styles)<Props>(RawAppShell);
```

I like this approach much more also with the trade-off of adding this prefix.

## Other Solutions

How do you handle this in your projects? Is there already a best-practice solution out there? It is very important for me that I have an named export for my component so I could not accept a solution with an default export at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about decorator syntax? `@withStyles` one line before `export const AppShell...`. I didn't try with Typescript, but in regular js works fine. Though requires babel plugin to transpile this syntax.

Comment: @EgorStambakio sadly not: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Answer (score 2):

Just do it in a single statement:

```
export const AppShell: React.SFC<Props> = withStyles(styles)<Props>((props: Props) => (
  …
));
```

Comment: This solution I also had in mind but I think this will end up in a mess if you need more than one HOC. Also, I plan to use Redux in my Application and then I would use the compose(https://redux.js.org/api/compose) feature from Redux. So I think this solution isn't the right one for me.

Comment: That just means you can *compose* the HOCs to one HOC, and then use that on the arrow function?

Comment: I think this would be really messy.

Comment: Either put the `compose` result into a temporary variable, or use indentation (every `compose` argument on its own line)

Comment: You do this also in your projects? But I think I will try this and I will see how it feels. Thank you!

Comment: @Nico Tbh I don't use React at all :-)